# Difference between Ти and тi

Tags: різниця-між-словами

There is a song where they make it with the different letters for an "i" sound.
Last line:

*Шукай в телефонi мiй слiд

Цiлуй в вiкно мої губи

Як знак на моєму плечi

Ти квiтка, тi квiтка*

And I would like to know the difference.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand, it's just “ти квітка, ти квітка” (twice the same). If you were listening the audio, maybe pronunciation specifics of a particular singer caused you to misinterpret it; if you were reading the written lyrics, then maybe there was just a typo.

Ukrainian really has the word “ти” (*you*, in singular) and “ті” (*those*, in plural). But:

- “ти квітка” is a correct phrase, it means *you're a flower* (literally *you flower*, as we don't use articles and rarely use *to be* in Ukrainian);
- “ті квітка” means nothing, these wordforms can't be combined (“т**а** кві́тка” — *that flower*, “ті квітк**и́**” — *those flowers*; i.e. you need to change either the first word to singular or the second word to plural but can't just put together plural “ті” and singular “кві́тка”).

[The official audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8fGSmP3D38) is available on YouTube. Also [some version of lyrics](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%95%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B8/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) is available on musixmatch. Here's the corresponding part:

> Шукай в телефоні мій слід
> Цілуй у вікно мої губи
> Як знак на моєму плечі, **ти квітка (Ти квітка-а-а!)**

So, it's simply twice the same. (Second “ти квітка” is put into parentheses, because the backing vocalists sing it instead of the lead singer; and also second “квітка” is spelled as “квітка-а-а” to denote specific manner of singing. But from the lyrics perspective it's nothing more than echoing/reverberating the preceding words.)